# PySpark DataFrames - way to enumerate without converting to Pandas?

Tags: python, apache-spark, bigdata, pyspark, rdd

I have a very big **pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame** named df. 
I need some way of enumerating records- thus, being able to access record with certain index. (or select group of records with indexes range)

In pandas, I could make just

```
indexes=[2,3,6,7] 
df[indexes]
```

Here I want something similar, *(and without converting dataframe to pandas)*

The closest I can get to is:

- Enumerating all the objects in the original dataframe by:

  ```
  indexes=np.arange(df.count())
  df_indexed=df.withColumn('index', indexes)
  ```

  - Searching for  values I need using where() function.

QUESTIONS:

1. Why it doesn't work and how to make it working? How to add a row to a dataframe?
2. Would it work later to make something like:

   ```
    indexes=[2,3,6,7] 
    df1.where("index in indexes").collect()
   ```
3. Any faster and simpler way to deal with it?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It doesn't work because:

1. the second argument for `withColumn` should be a `Column` not a collection. `np.array` won't work here
2. when you pass `"index in indexes"` as a SQL expression to `where` `indexes` is out of scope and it is not resolved as a valid identifier

**PySpark >= 1.4.0**

<s>You can add row numbers using respective window function and query using `Column.isin` method or properly formated query string:</s>

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, rowNumber
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

w = Window.orderBy()
indexed = df.withColumn("index", rowNumber().over(w))

# Using DSL
indexed.where(col("index").isin(set(indexes)))

# Using SQL expression
indexed.where("index in ({0})".format(",".join(str(x) for x in indexes)))
```

It looks like window functions called without `PARTITION BY` clause move all data to the single partition so above may be not the best solution after all.

> Any faster and simpler way to deal with it?

Not really. Spark DataFrames don't support random row access.

`PairedRDD` can be accessed using `lookup` method which is relatively fast if data is partitioned using `HashPartitioner`. There is also [indexed-rdd](https://github.com/amplab/spark-indexedrdd) project which supports efficient lookups.

**Edit**:

Independent  of PySpark version you can try something like this:

```
from pyspark.sql import Row
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, LongType

row = Row("char")
row_with_index = Row("char", "index")

df = sc.parallelize(row(chr(x)) for x in range(97, 112)).toDF()
df.show(5)

## +----+
## |char|
## +----+
## |   a|
## |   b|
## |   c|
## |   d|
## |   e|
## +----+
## only showing top 5 rows

# This part is not tested but should work and save some work later
schema  = StructType(
    df.schema.fields[:] + [StructField("index", LongType(), False)])

indexed = (df.rdd # Extract rdd
    .zipWithIndex() # Add index
    .map(lambda ri: row_with_index(*list(ri[0]) + [ri[1]])) # Map to rows
    .toDF(schema)) # It will work without schema but will be more expensive

# inSet in Spark < 1.3
indexed.where(col("index").isin(indexes))
```

Comment: Hello @zero323, I tried the snippet. Everything works except  `indexed.where(col("index").inSet(indexes))` that doesn't work. It returns `TypeError: 'Column' object is not callable` for me. Do you have an update on the snippet if I want to query multiple indexes?

Answer (score 13):

If you want a number range that's guaranteed not to collide but does not require a `.over(partitionBy())` then you can use `monotonicallyIncreasingId()`.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import monotonicallyIncreasingId
df.select(monotonicallyIncreasingId().alias("rowId"),"*")
```

Note though that the values are not particularly "neat". Each partition is given a value range and the output will not be contiguous. E.g. `0, 1, 2, 8589934592, 8589934593, 8589934594`.

This was added to Spark on Apr 28, 2015 here: https://github.com/apache/spark/commit/d94cd1a733d5715792e6c4eac87f0d5c81aebbe2

Answer (score 2):

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import monotonically_increasing_id
df.withColumn("Atr4", monotonically_increasing_id())
```

> If you only need incremental values (like an ID) and if there is no
>   constraint that the numbers need to be consecutive, you could use
>   monotonically_increasing_id(). The only guarantee when using this
>   function is that the values will be increasing for each row, however,
>   the values themself can differ each execution.

Answer (score 1):

You certainly can add an array for indexing, an array of your choice indeed:
In Scala, first we need to create an indexing Array:

```
val index_array=(1 to df.count.toInt).toArray

index_array: Array[Int] = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)
```

You can now append this column to your DF. First, For that, you need to open up our DF and get it as an array, then zip it with your index_array and then we convert the new array back into and RDD. The final step is to get it as a DF:

```
final_df = sc.parallelize((df.collect.map(
    x=>(x(0),x(1))) zip index_array).map(
    x=>(x._1._1.toString,x._1._2.toString,x._2))).
    toDF("column_name")
```

The indexing would be more clear after that.

Answer (score -1):

`monotonicallyIncreasingId()` - this will assign row numbers in incresing order but not in sequence.

sample output with 2 columns:

`|---------------------|------------------|
|      RowNo          |     Heading 2    |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          1          |         xy       |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          12         |         xz       |
|---------------------|------------------|`

If you want assign row numbers use following trick.

Tested in spark-2.0.1 and greater versions.

`df.createOrReplaceTempView("df")
dfRowId = spark.sql("select *, row_number() over (partition by 0) as rowNo from df")`

sample output with 2 columns:

`|---------------------|------------------|
|      RowNo          |     Heading 2    |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          1          |         xy       |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          2          |         xz       |
|---------------------|------------------|`

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

Selecting a single row *n* of a Pyspark DataFrame, try:

```
df.where(df.id == n).show()
```

Given a Pyspark DataFrame:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([(1, 143.5, 5.6, 28, 'M', 100000),\
                          (2, 167.2, 5.4, 45, 'M', None),\
                          (3, None , 5.2, None, None, None),\
                          ], ['id', 'weight', 'height', 'age', 'gender', 'income'])
```

Selecting the 3rd row, try:

```
df.where('id == 3').show()
```

Or:

```
df.where(df.id == 3).show()
```

Selecting multiple rows with rows' ids (the 2nd & the 3rd rows in this case), try:

```
id = {"2", "3"}
df.where(df.id.isin(id)).show()
```

Comment: This answer is downvoted because it does not explain how to create the id column.