# How do I add a new column to a Spark DataFrame (using PySpark)?

Tags: python, apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a Spark DataFrame (using PySpark 1.5.1) and would like to add a new column.

I've tried the following without any success:

```
type(randomed_hours) # => list

# Create in Python and transform to RDD

new_col = pd.DataFrame(randomed_hours, columns=['new_col'])

spark_new_col = sqlContext.createDataFrame(new_col)

my_df_spark.withColumn("hours", spark_new_col["new_col"])
```

Also got an error using this:

```
my_df_spark.withColumn("hours",  sc.parallelize(randomed_hours))
```

So how do I add a new column (based on Python vector) to an existing DataFrame with PySpark?

Answer (score 276, accepted):

You cannot add an arbitrary column to a `DataFrame` in Spark. New columns can be created only by using literals (other literal types are described in [How to add a constant column in a Spark DataFrame?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32788322))

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import lit

df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(
    [(1, "a", 23.0), (3, "B", -23.0)], ("x1", "x2", "x3"))

df_with_x4 = df.withColumn("x4", lit(0))
df_with_x4.show()

## +---+---+-----+---+
## | x1| x2|   x3| x4|
## +---+---+-----+---+
## |  1|  a| 23.0|  0|
## |  3|  B|-23.0|  0|
## +---+---+-----+---+
```

transforming an existing column:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import exp

df_with_x5 = df_with_x4.withColumn("x5", exp("x3"))
df_with_x5.show()

## +---+---+-----+---+--------------------+
## | x1| x2|   x3| x4|                  x5|
## +---+---+-----+---+--------------------+
## |  1|  a| 23.0|  0| 9.744803446248903E9|
## |  3|  B|-23.0|  0|1.026187963170189...|
## +---+---+-----+---+--------------------+
```

included using `join`:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import exp

lookup = sqlContext.createDataFrame([(1, "foo"), (2, "bar")], ("k", "v"))
df_with_x6 = (df_with_x5
    .join(lookup, col("x1") == col("k"), "leftouter")
    .drop("k")
    .withColumnRenamed("v", "x6"))

## +---+---+-----+---+--------------------+----+
## | x1| x2|   x3| x4|                  x5|  x6|
## +---+---+-----+---+--------------------+----+
## |  1|  a| 23.0|  0| 9.744803446248903E9| foo|
## |  3|  B|-23.0|  0|1.026187963170189...|null|
## +---+---+-----+---+--------------------+----+
```

or generated with function / udf:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import rand

df_with_x7 = df_with_x6.withColumn("x7", rand())
df_with_x7.show()

## +---+---+-----+---+--------------------+----+-------------------+
## | x1| x2|   x3| x4|                  x5|  x6|                 x7|
## +---+---+-----+---+--------------------+----+-------------------+
## |  1|  a| 23.0|  0| 9.744803446248903E9| foo|0.41930610446846617|
## |  3|  B|-23.0|  0|1.026187963170189...|null|0.37801881545497873|
## +---+---+-----+---+--------------------+----+-------------------+
```

Performance-wise, built-in functions (`pyspark.sql.functions`), which map to Catalyst expression, are usually preferred over Python user defined functions.

If you want to add content of an arbitrary RDD as a column you can

- add [row numbers to existing data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32761138/1560062)
- call `zipWithIndex` on RDD and convert it to data frame
- join both using index as a join key

Comment: "New columns can be created only by using literals" What exactly does literals mean in this context?

Comment: Spark's Documentation is great, see df.withColumn http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.withColumn

Comment: Spark documentation is "great" only in that it leaves great swaths of usage up to an exercise for the astute reader. Spark (and Pyspark) covers a veritable zoo of data structures, with little or no instruction on how to convert among them. Case in point: proliferation of questions just like this one.

Answer (score 71):

To add a column using a UDF:

```
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(
    [(1, "a", 23.0), (3, "B", -23.0)], ("x1", "x2", "x3"))

from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
from pyspark.sql.types import *

def valueToCategory(value):
   if   value == 1: return 'cat1'
   elif value == 2: return 'cat2'
   ...
   else: return 'n/a'

# NOTE: it seems that calls to udf() must be after SparkContext() is called
udfValueToCategory = udf(valueToCategory, StringType())
df_with_cat = df.withColumn("category", udfValueToCategory("x1"))
df_with_cat.show()

## +---+---+-----+---------+
## | x1| x2|   x3| category|
## +---+---+-----+---------+
## |  1|  a| 23.0|     cat1|
## |  3|  B|-23.0|      n/a|
## +---+---+-----+---------+
```

Answer (score 32):

For [Spark 2.0](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.select)

```
# assumes schema has 'age' column 
df.select('*', (df.age + 10).alias('agePlusTen'))
```

Comment: Needs to be df.select('*', (df.age + 10).alias('agePlusTen'))

Comment: Thanks, and if you enter `df = df.select('*', (df.age + 10).alias('agePlusTen'))` you are effectively _adding an arbitrary column_ as @zero323 warned us above was impossible, unless there's something wrong with doing this in Spark, in Pandas it's the standard way..

Comment: Is there is a version of this for pySpark?

Comment: @Tagar Above snippet is python.

Comment: To add 2 new columns in one call to df.select, how would you do it?  I actually have about 200,000 new columns but doing 2 should be the same.

Comment: @GeoffreyAnderson, `df.select('*', df.age + 10, df.age + 20)`

Answer (score 13):

There are multiple ways we can add a new column in pySpark.

Let's first create a simple DataFrame.

```
date = [27, 28, 29, None, 30, 31]
df = spark.createDataFrame(date, IntegerType())
```

Now let's try to double the column value and store it in a new column. PFB few different approaches to achieve the same.

```
# Approach - 1 : using withColumn function
df.withColumn("double", df.value * 2).show()

# Approach - 2 : using select with alias function.
df.select("*", (df.value * 2).alias("double")).show()

# Approach - 3 : using selectExpr function with as clause.
df.selectExpr("*", "value * 2 as double").show()

# Approach - 4 : Using as clause in SQL statement.
df.createTempView("temp")
spark.sql("select *, value * 2 as double from temp").show()
```

For more examples and explanation on spark DataFrame functions, you can visit my [blog](https://medium.com/expedia-group-tech/start-your-journey-with-apache-spark-part-2-682891efda4b).

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

To add new column with some custom value or dynamic value calculation which will be populated based on the existing columns.

e.g.

```
|ColumnA | ColumnB |
|--------|---------|
| 10     | 15      |
| 10     | 20      |
| 10     | 30      |
```

and new ColumnC as ColumnA+ColumnB

```
|ColumnA | ColumnB | ColumnC|
|--------|---------|--------|
| 10     | 15      | 25     |
| 10     | 20      | 30     |
| 10     | 30      | 40     |
```

using

```
#to add new column
def customColumnVal(row):
    rd=row.asDict()
    rd["ColumnC"]=row["ColumnA"] + row["ColumnB"]
    
    new_row=Row(**rd)
    return new_row

#convert DF to RDD
df_rdd= input_dataframe.rdd

#apply new fucntion to rdd
output_dataframe=df_rdd.map(customColumnVal).toDF()
```

`input_dataframe` is the dataframe which will get modified and `customColumnVal` function is having code to add new column.

Comment: in This I am getting error customColumnVal needs one positional argument row

Answer (score 2):

We can add additional columns to DataFrame directly with below steps:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import when
df = spark.createDataFrame([["amit", 30], ["rohit", 45], ["sameer", 50]], ["name", "age"])
df = df.withColumn("profile", when(df.age >= 40, "Senior").otherwise("Executive"))
df.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define a new `udf` when adding a `column_name`:

```
u_f = F.udf(lambda :yourstring,StringType())
a.select(u_f().alias('column_name')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
from pyspark.sql.types import *
func_name = udf(
    lambda val: val, # do sth to val
    StringType()
)
df.withColumn('new_col', func_name(df.old_col))
```

Comment: You need to call `StringType()`.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to offer a generalized example for a very similar use case:

Use Case: I have a csv consisting of:

```
First|Third|Fifth
data|data|data
data|data|data
...billion more lines
```

I need to perform some transformations and the final csv needs to look like

```
First|Second|Third|Fourth|Fifth
data|null|data|null|data
data|null|data|null|data
...billion more lines
```

I need to do this because this is the schema defined by some model and I need for my final data to be interoperable with SQL Bulk Inserts and such things.

so:

1) I read the original csv using spark.read and call it "df".

2) I do something to the data.

3) I add the null columns using this script:

```
outcols = []
for column in MY_COLUMN_LIST:
    if column in df.columns:
        outcols.append(column)
    else:
        outcols.append(lit(None).cast(StringType()).alias('{0}'.format(column)))

df = df.select(outcols)
```

In this way, you can structure your schema after loading a csv (would also work for reordering columns if you have to do this for many tables).

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to add a column is to use "withColumn". Since the dataframe is created using sqlContext, you have to specify the schema or by default can be available in the dataset. If the schema is specified, the workload becomes tedious when changing every time.

Below is an example that you can consider:

```
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
from pyspark.sql.types import *
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc) # SparkContext will be sc by default 

# Read the dataset of your choice (Already loaded with schema)
Data = sqlContext.read.csv("/path", header = True/False, schema = "infer", sep = "delimiter")

# For instance the data has 30 columns from col1, col2, ... col30. If you want to add a 31st column, you can do so by the following:
Data = Data.withColumn("col31", "Code goes here")

# Check the change 
Data.printSchema()
```

Answer (score 0):

in pyspark 3.2+，you can use：

```
my_df_spark.pandas_api().assign(hours=spark_new_col.pandas_api()['new_col']).to_spark().show()
```