# Creating a pyspark.sql.dataframe out of two columns in two different pyspark.sql.dataframes in PySpark

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-2.0

Assume the following two Dataframes in pyspark with equal number of rows:
df1:
 |_ Column1a
 |_ Column1b

df2:
 |_ Column2a
 |_ Column2b

I wish to create a a new DataFrame "df" which has Column1a and Column 2a only. What could be the best possible solution for it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I add a new column to a Spark DataFrame (using PySpark)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33681487/how-do-i-add-a-new-column-to-a-spark-dataframe-using-pyspark)

Comment: The solution looks at transforming existing Columns in a dataframe or creating a new column, whereas I want to pick Column1a and Column1b to form a new Dataframe.

Comment: Is the context of the join based on the position?   For example, would using the `rownumber()` approach in this answer work?  http://stackoverflow.com/a/40626348/1100699

Comment: I need to give this a try, that might just do it. I'll try it over the weekend. Thanks for the help. I'll get back about how it goes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Denny Lee's answer is the way.
It involves creating another column on both the DataFrames which is the *Unique_Row_ID* for every row. We then perform a join on *Unique_Row_ID*. And then drop *Unique_Row_ID* if required.