# I am doing a filter and count on the pyspark dataframe col..how to store the result in another col in the same dataframe?

Tags: pyspark

I want to store the result of below line in a col in the same df dataframe.

`df.filter(F.abs(df.Px)< 0.005).count()`

How can I do that?

Comment: have you already seen this [stackoverflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33681487/how-do-i-add-a-new-column-to-a-spark-dataframe-using-pyspark)? I think you can find your answer there.

Comment: Thanks titiro89 for your response but when i use the withColumn df=df.withColumn("new",df.filter(F.abs(df.Px)< 0.005).count())                     
 i am getting the follwing error: col should be Column  because the value returned is int. please provide your inputs on this

Comment: Could you provide a brief example of what your df and your F are?

Comment: df is my pyspark dataframe and  import pyspark.sql.functions as F

Comment: Ok, but if you want to be helped by the other users, you have to provide more code than that, you have to tell which is your starting point, what you want to get, also specify the meaning of your variables, as you can see at this link: [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

The answer is you can do that using `union`. However, it's not a good practice to append the row below particular column because you can also have multiple columns and that will give you only one extra row with new count value.

I give an example snippet below.

```
from pyspark.sql import Row

df = spark.createDataFrame(pd.DataFrame([0.01, 0.003, 0.004, 0.005, 0.02], 
                                        columns=['Px']))
n_px = df.filter(func.abs(df['Px']) < 0.005).count() # count
df_count = spark.sparkContext.parallelize([Row(**{'Px': n_px})]).toDF() # new dataframe for count
df_union = df.union(df_count)

+-----+
|   Px|
+-----+
| 0.01|
|0.003|
|0.004|
|0.005|
| 0.02|
|  2.0|
+-----+
```