# How can I sum multiple columns in a spark dataframe in pyspark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I've got a list of column names I want to sum

```
columns = ['col1','col2','col3']
```

How can I add the three and put it in a new column ? (in an automatic way, so that I can change the column list and have new results)

Dataframe with result I want:

```
col1   col2   col3   result
 1      2      3       6
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I add a new column to a Spark DataFrame (using PySpark)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33681487/how-do-i-add-a-new-column-to-a-spark-dataframe-using-pyspark)

Comment: Thanks for answering ! I know how to add columns, i just want an efficient way to add them based on a list with column names.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this:

```
df = df.withColumn('result', sum(df[col] for col in df.columns))
```

`df.columns` will be list of columns from df.

Comment: I have replicate the same with below dataframe and getting an error:  listA = [(10,20,40,60),(10,10,10,40)]
df = spark.createDataFrame(listA, ['M1','M2','M3','M4'])   newdf = df.withColumn('result', sum(df[col] for col in df.columns)) Please see below error.  TypeError: 'Column' object is not callable. Am I missing something??

Answer (score 33):

###### [TL;DR,]

You can do this:

```
from functools import reduce
from operator import add
from pyspark.sql.functions import col

df.na.fill(0).withColumn("result" ,reduce(add, [col(x) for x in df.columns]))
```

#### Explanation:

The `df.na.fill(0)` portion is to handle nulls in your data. If you don't have any nulls, you can skip that and do this instead:

```
df.withColumn("result" ,reduce(add, [col(x) for x in df.columns]))
```

If you have static list of columns, you can do this:

```
df.withColumn("result", col("col1") + col("col2") + col("col3"))
```

But if you don't want to type the whole columns list, you need to generate the phrase `col("col1") + col("col2") + col("col3")` iteratively. For this, you can use the `reduce` method with `add` function to get this:

```
reduce(add, [col(x) for x in df.columns])
```

The columns are added two at a time, so you would get `col(col("col1") + col("col2")) + col("col3")` instead of `col("col1") + col("col2") + col("col3")`. But the effect would be same.

The `col(x)` ensures that you are getting `col(col("col1") + col("col2")) + col("col3")` instead of a simple string concat (which generates (`col1col2col3`).

Answer (score 11):

## Add multiple columns from a list into one column

I tried a lot of methods and the following are my observations:

1. PySpark's `sum` function doesn't support column addition (Pyspark version 2.3.1)
2. Built-in python's `sum` function is working for some folks but giving error for others.

So, the addition of multiple columns can be achieved using the `expr` function in PySpark, which takes an expression to be computed as an input.

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import expr

cols_list = ['a', 'b', 'c']

# Creating an addition expression using `join`
expression = '+'.join(cols_list)

df = df.withColumn('sum_cols', expr(expression))
```

This gives us the desired sum of columns. We can also use any other complex expression to get other output.