# PySpark: Sum up columns from array

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I want to sum up all columns that have a specific string in name ('scr_') into a new column. I checked this [How can I sum multiple columns in a spark dataframe in pyspark?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53297872/how-can-i-sum-multiple-columns-in-a-spark-dataframe-in-pyspark), but for me it is not working ... whats going wrong?

```
from pyspark.sql.types import *
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql import Window 
from functools import reduce
from operator import add

def script():
  points = [s for s in df.columns if 'scr_' in s]
  df = df.withColumn('TOTAL', F.sum([df[col] for col in points]))
```

This gives me: `TypeError: 'Column' object is not callable`

Thank you!

Comment: The answer is in the linked post. You need to use Python `sum` not pyspark function `F.sum()`

Comment: Yes it does, thank you. Didn't know there was a difference between these two ```sum``` functions.