# pyspark aggregation based on key and value expanded in multiple columns

Tags: pyspark

I am trying to find the sum of value column based on code column in a table in the below format using pyspark. Here in this example, I have provided only 3 code and its respective value columns, but in real scenario it can be up to 100.

Table A

| id1 | item | code_1 | Value_1 | code_2 | Value_2 | code_3 | value_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 1 | A | 5 | X | 10 | L | 20 |
| 100 | 2 | B | 5 | L | 10 | A | 20 |

Expected output:

| id1 | item | sum_A | sum_X | sum_L | sum B | Total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 1 | 25 | 10 | 30 | 5 | 70 |
| 100 | 2 | 25 | 10 | 30 | 5 | 70 |

Can someone help me to find a logic to accomplish this output.

Comment: how does 100,2 gets sum_a as 25?

Comment: For tax_code A there are 2 values for id1 100, one is 5 and other is 20. So total 25. And this is updated in both rows for id1=100

Comment: Added a new column Total in the output table

Comment: Open as a new question..

Comment: for total, check if this helps or not. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53297872/how-can-i-sum-multiple-columns-in-a-spark-dataframe-in-pyspark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Stack + groupBy + Pivot` functions for this case.

**`Example:`**

```
df.show()
df1 = df.select("id1",'item',expr("stack(3,code_1,value_1,code_2,value_2,code_3,value_3)")).\
  groupBy("id1","col0").agg(sum("col1").alias("sum")).\
    withColumn("col0",concat(lit("sum_"),col("col0")))
df.select("id1","item").distinct().\
  join(df1,['id1']).\
    groupBy("id1","item").\
      pivot("col0").\
        agg(first(col("sum").alias("sum_"))).\
        show()
```

---

**`Output:`**

```
#sample data
+---+----+------+-------+------+-------+------+-------+
|id1|item|code_1|value_1|code_2|value_2|code_3|value_3|
+---+----+------+-------+------+-------+------+-------+
|100|   1|     A|      5|     X|     10|     L|     20|
|100|   2|     B|      5|     L|     10|     A|     20|
+---+----+------+-------+------+-------+------+-------+

#output    
+---+----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|id1|item|sum_A|sum_B|sum_L|sum_X|
+---+----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|100|   2|   25|    5|   30|   10|
|100|   1|   25|    5|   30|   10|
+---+----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
```

---

**`UPDATE:`**

**`Dynamic sql:`**

```
req_cols = [c for c in df.columns if c.startswith("code_") or c.startswith("value_")]

sql_expr = "stack("+ str(int(len(req_cols)/2))+"," +','.join(req_cols) +")"

df.show()
df1 = df.select("id1",'item',expr(f"{sql_expr}")).\
  groupBy("id1","col0").agg(sum("col1").alias("sum")).\
    withColumn("col0",concat(lit("sum_"),col("col0")))
df.select("id1","item").distinct().\
  join(df1,['id1']).\
    groupBy("id1","item").\
      pivot("col0").\
        agg(first(col("sum").alias("sum_"))).\
        show()
```

Comment: The no: of columns range upto 100

Comment: you can dynamically do `stack` based on `df.columns` list

Comment: @AmruthaK Added dynamic sql for 100 columns..

Answer (score 0):

alternative approach using window function.

The first part is mostly same as @notNull.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
n = 3
melt_cols = ','.join([f'code_{x}, Value_{x}' for x in range(1, n+1)])

df = (df.select('id1', 'item', 
                F.expr(f'stack({n}, {melt_cols}) AS (code, value)'))
      .groupby('id1', 'item')
      .pivot('code')
      .agg(F.sum('value')))
```

This will result in aggregate per id1 & item.

```
+---+----+---+----+---+----+
|id1|item|  A|   B|  L|   X|
+---+----+---+----+---+----+
|100|   2| 20|   5| 10|null|
|100|   1|  5|null| 20|  10|
+---+----+---+----+---+----+
```

Then, use the window function to aggregate per id1.

```
df = df.select('id1', 'item', 
               *[F.sum(x).over(Window.partitionBy('id1')).alias(f'sum_{x}') 
                 for x in df.columns if x not in ['id1', 'item']])
```

Final result

```
+---+----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|id1|item|sum_A|sum_B|sum_L|sum_X|
+---+----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|100|   2|   25|    5|   30|   10|
|100|   1|   25|    5|   30|   10|
+---+----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
```