# Adding a List element as a column to existing pyspark dataframe

Tags: python, pyspark

I have a list `lists=[0,1,2,3,5,6,7]`. Order is not sequential. I have a pyspark dataframe with 9 columns.

```
+-------------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+---------------+-----+----+
|               date|ftt (°c)|rtt (°c)|fbt (°c)|rbt (°c)|fmt (°c)|rmt (°c)|fmhhumidityunit|index|Diff|
+-------------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+---------------+-----+----+
|2019-02-01 05:29:47|     NaN|     NaN|     NaN|     NaN|     NaN|     NaN|            NaN|    0| NaN|
|2019-02-01 05:29:17|     NaN|     NaN|     NaN|     NaN|     NaN|    NaN|           NaN|    1| NaN |
```

I need to add my lists as a column to my existing dataframe. My lists is not in order so iam not able to use udf. Is there a way to do it?.Please help me
I want it to be like this

```
+-------------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+---------------+-----+----+------+
|               date|ftt (°c)|rtt (°c)|fbt (°c)|rbt (°c)|fmt (°c)|rmt (°c)|fmhhumidityunit|index|Diff|lists |
+-------------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+---------------+-----+----+-------+
|2019-02-01 05:29:47|     NaN|     NaN|     NaN|     NaN|     NaN|     NaN|            NaN|    0| NaN|0     |
|2019-02-01 05:29:17|     NaN|     NaN|     NaN|     NaN|     NaN|     NaN|           NaN|    1| NaN |1     |
```

Comment: can you show us how would you like to add this list to your existing dataframe?

Comment: I have added how  the dataframe should look like. I have added only two rows but main problem is to added a column to my dataframe and I have a lists.

Comment: Not iterate but just added my lists of values as a new column to to my existing dataframe.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I add a new column to a Spark DataFrame (using PySpark)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33681487/how-do-i-add-a-new-column-to-a-spark-dataframe-using-pyspark)

Comment: @Daniel its different question. I have a list and I want to add it as a column to my dataframe

Comment: Should the first item of your list be assigned to the row with the earliest date (i.e. is your dataframe ordered by date)?

Comment: @cronoik. It is ordered by date. Suppose I have a dataframe with Row=7 and column=9. I have a list where its length is 7. I need this list to be added as a new column to my dataframe. So my resultant dataframe will have 10 column.

Comment: I just saw that you have in index column. Is it consecutive, starting from `0` and can I also say that first index of your list belongs to first the row with index `0`? I'm asking this question because pyspark dataframes are not ordered (like pandas) and to conduct such an operation requires a column which allows you to order your dataframe.

Comment: Will something like below work? list = [(1,'DEF'),(2,'KLM')]
df=spark.createDataFrame(list, ['id', 'value'])

lists=[5,6]
rdd = sc.parallelize(lists)
df=df.rdd.zip(rdd).map(lambda x: (x[0][0],x[0][1],x[1])).toDF(["id", "Value" , "index"])

Comment: you can create rdd from given list and zip it with the existing dataframe and can use map operation on it. but the given list items and dataframe rows has to be same for above method.

Comment: Thanks but can you explain `x[0][0],x[0][1],x[1]`. Is it dynamic?. Solution should work for any number of columns. length of lists is equal to dataframe rows.

Comment: @cronoik..yes its consecutive only. but the elements in the lists are not consecutive.

Comment: @user-2147482338. if the length of list and dataframe rows are equal above will work for any number of columns. you just need to include each each column element into your map function.

Comment: or can use some list comprehension to exclude coding it separately for each element.

Comment: @vikrantrana thanks a lot. so `x[0][0],x[0][1],x[1]` will work for any number of column right?

Comment: No. it was specific to my dataframe which is having two columns. you may need to include your columns as an element or can use some list comprehensions. I will give a try after some time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not too sure if it has to be something like this or were you expecting something else.
If your number of list items and dataframe rows has to be same then here's a simple approach.

For a given sample dataframe with three columns:

```
 l = [(1,'DEF',33),(2,'KLM',22),(3,'ABC',32),(4,'XYZ',77)]
 df=spark.createDataFrame(l, ['id', 'value','age'])
```

Lets say here's a list:

```
lists=[5,6,7,8]
```

Can create a rdd from this list and use a zip function with the dataframe and use map function over it.

```
listrdd = sc.parallelize(lists)

newdf=df.rdd.zip(listrdd).map(lambda (x,y ) : ([x for x in x] + [y])).toDF(["id", "Value",",age","List_element"])

>>> ziprdd=df.rdd.zip(listrdd)
>>> ziprdd.take(50)
[(Row(id=1, value=u'DEF', age=33), 5), (Row(id=2, value=u'KLM', age=22), 6), (Row(id=3, value=u'ABC', age=32), 7), (Row(id=4, value=u'XYZ', age=77), 8)]
```

As zip function return key value pairs having first element contains data from first rdd and second element contains data from second rdd.
I am using list comprehension for first element and concatenating it with second element.

It's dynamic and can work for n number of columns but list elements and dataframe rows has to be same.

```
>>> newdf.show()
]+---+-----+----+------------+
| id|Value|,age|List_element|
+---+-----+----+------------+
|  1|  DEF|  33|           5|
|  2|  KLM|  22|           6|
|  3|  ABC|  32|           7|
|  4|  XYZ|  77|           8|
+---+-----+----+------------+
```

**Note:** Both rdd partition count has to be same for using zip method else you will get an error

```
ValueError: Can only zip with RDD which has the same number of partitions
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.I was expecting like this. I will try this. Thanks for helping me.

Comment: Iam getting `ValueError: Can only zip with RDD which has the same number of partitions`.

Comment: I find that `df.rdd.getNumPartitions() != listrdd.getNumPartitions()`..Any idea of how to solve it?

Comment: Yes. whats is the partition count for your list and dataframe. It has to be same for zip function.

Comment: may be we can keep the partition same or else need to look for another approach.. one possible way to use zipwithindex and join on index keys.. Just thinking

Comment: df has 2 and listrdd has 8 partitionNumber.

Comment: I repartitioned the listdd to 2 but now iam getting `TypeError: <lambda>() missing 1 required positional argument: 'y'`. Can you help me with this pls

Comment: It shouldn't be a problem.. are you using same map?

Comment: I think tuple unpacking is removed in lambda function.

Answer (score 0):

you can `join` two dfs, like this:

```
df2 = spark.createDataFrame()
df= df.join(df2, on=['index']).drop('index')
```

df2 will contain the columns you wish to add to the main df.