# How to create datetime columns in a pyspark dataframe?

Tags: python, pyspark

I have a pyspark dataframe that looks like the following

```
    df
    
       year   month   day 
       2017    9       3 
       2015    5      16
```

I would like to create a column as `datetime` like the following

```
    df
    
       year   month   day           date
       2017    9       3    2017-09-03 00:00:00
       2015    5      16    2017-05-16 00:00:00
```

Comment: Have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33683462/14246131) to a similar question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`concat_ws`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.concat_ws) to concat and convert to `date` using [`to_date`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.to_date)

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
df = spark.createDataFrame([[2017,9,3 ],[2015,5,16]],['year', 'month','date'])
df = df.withColumn('timestamp',to_date(concat_ws('-', df.year, df.month,df.date)))
df.show()

+----+-----+----+----------+
|year|month|date| timestamp|
+----+-----+----+----------+
|2017|    9|   3|2017-09-03|
|2015|    5|  16|2015-05-16|
+----+-----+----+----------+
```

**Schema:**

```
df.printSchema()
root
 |-- year: long (nullable = true)
 |-- month: long (nullable = true)
 |-- date: long (nullable = true)
 |-- timestamp: date (nullable = true)
```

Comment: Getting this error on using this - `.DateTimeParseException: Text '2020-7-01' could not be parsed at index 5`