# Spark sql row_number or sequence number?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

random number generator SparkSQL ?

For example:

- Netezza: sequence number
- mysql: sequence number

Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/32760888/1560062

Comment: Sorry, but I really don't understand what he is asking for.

Answer (score 2):

Sequence in spark sql is in spark 1.6 its select monotonically_increasing_id() from table , spark 1.6 is due to get released

Comment: here an example which works for Spark 2.2 sine_signale_no_ts.createOrReplaceTempView("signal")
sine_signale_my_ts = sql("select (monotonically_increasing_id()+1483228800)*1000 as ts, sine from signal")

Answer (score 1):

Spark Sql already have random functions there is one [blog](https://databricks.com/blog/2015/06/02/statistical-and-mathematical-functions-with-dataframes-in-spark.html).

Or for number of rows spark sql also have row_number() function.

Comment: Hi Kaushal, I tried row_number function but spark sql gave an error

Comment: sqlContext.sql("select * from (select column1,column2,column3,column4,column5 ,row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY column1 ORDER BY column1 DESC) rank as random from TestTable ) a")

Comment: what exception you are getting

Comment: Hi Kaushal, I got what I am looking for in spark 1.6 its select monotonically_increasing_id() from table , spark 1.6 is due to get released