# Spark: equivelant of zipwithindex in dataframe

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Assuming I am having the following dataframe:

```
dummy_data = [('a',1),('b',25),('c',3),('d',8),('e',1)]
df = sc.parallelize(dummy_data).toDF(['letter','number'])
```

And i want to create the following dataframe:

```
[('a',0),('b',2),('c',1),('d',3),('e',0)]
```

What I do is to convert it to `rdd` and use `zipWithIndex` function and after join the results:

```
convertDF = (df.select('number')
              .distinct()
              .rdd
              .zipWithIndex()
              .map(lambda x:(x[0].number,x[1]))
              .toDF(['old','new']))


finalDF = (df
            .join(convertDF,df.number == convertDF.old)
            .select(df.letter,convertDF.new))
```

Is if there is something similar function as `zipWIthIndex` in dataframes? Is there another more efficient way to do this task?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/32760888/1560062

Answer (score 9):

Please check https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-23074 for this direct functionality parity in dataframes .. upvote that jira if you're interested to see this at some point in Spark.

Here's a workaround though in PySpark:

```
def dfZipWithIndex (df, offset=1, colName="rowId"):
    '''
        Enumerates dataframe rows is native order, like rdd.ZipWithIndex(), but on a dataframe 
        and preserves a schema

        :param df: source dataframe
        :param offset: adjustment to zipWithIndex()'s index
        :param colName: name of the index column
    '''

    new_schema = StructType(
                    [StructField(colName,LongType(),True)]        # new added field in front
                    + df.schema.fields                            # previous schema
                )

    zipped_rdd = df.rdd.zipWithIndex()

    new_rdd = zipped_rdd.map(lambda args: ([args[1] + offset] + list(args[0])))

    return spark.createDataFrame(new_rdd, new_schema)
```

That's also available in [abalon](https://github.com/Tagar/abalon/blob/00e14d9711e65d244508182dd7c2a9c5be7ca2c7/abalon/spark/sparkutils.py#L115) package.

Comment: For Python 3+, need a minor change in this to make it work, because of the way map handles tuples. Following will work as tuple gets passed as single argument, using [] notation to read elements of the tuple,

new_rdd = zipped_rdd.map(lambda args: ([args[1] + offset] + list(args[0])))