# how to fetch the last row's 1st column value of spark scala dataframe inside the for and if loop

Tags: scala, apache-spark, for-loop, apache-spark-sql

`s_n181n` is a dataframe and here I go through the 3rd and 5th column of the dataframe row wise

and

where the column `nd` is `<=1.0` it breaks the code

[image]

```
ts(timestamp) | nd (nearest distance)
```

is the output columns, shown above

```
But what i need is the timestamp of last row value i.e 1529157727000
```

I want to break the loop showing last value of the loop
here. How to store that last row's timestamp value in a variable , so that outside this loop I can use it .

Comment: From the given example, it looks like the dataframe is sorted and you are trying to get the max value of the `ts` column. Is that correct?

Comment: You can order by desc and select the time stamp example, based on df.first, right?
OR refer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39544796/pyspark-spark-how-to-select-last-row-and-also-how-to-access-pyspark-dataframe-b

Comment: @jegan yes i want to get the max value of ts for that particular data when condition satisfied. if i use max(ts) then it will go and get the next max of whole dataset(ts).which i donot for this break condition only i need the max timestamp where it breaks the loop

Answer (score 1):

Here's my understanding of your requirement based on your question description and comment:

> Loop through the `collect`-ed RDD row-wise, and whenever `nd` in the
>   current row is less than or equal to the `ndLimit`, extract `ts` from
>   the previous row and reset `ndLimit` to value of `nd` from that same
>   row.

If that's correct, I would suggest using `foldLeft` to assemble the list of timestamps, as shown below:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row

val s_n181n = Seq(
  (1, "a1", 101L, "b1", 1.0),  // nd 1.0 is the initial limit
  (2, "a2", 102L, "b2", 1.6),
  (3, "a3", 103L, "b3", 1.2),
  (4, "a4", 104L, "b4", 0.8),  // 0.8 <= 1.0, hence ts 103 is saved and nd 1.2 is the new limit
  (5, "a5", 105L, "b5", 1.5),
  (6, "a6", 106L, "b6", 1.3),
  (7, "a7", 107L, "b7", 1.1),  // 1.1 <= 1.2, hence ts 106 is saved and nd 1.3 is the new limit
  (8, "a8", 108L, "b8", 1.2)   // 1.2 <= 1.3, hence ts 107 is saved and nd 1.1 is the new limit
).toDF("c1", "c2", "ts", "c4", "nd")

val s_rows = s_n181n.rdd.collect

val s_list = s_rows.map(r => (r.getAs[Long](2), r.getAs[Double](4))).toList
// List[(Long, Double)] = List(
//   (101,1.0), (102,1.6), (103,1.2), (104,0.8), (105,1.5), (106,1.3), (107,1.1), (108,1.2)
// )

val ndLimit = s_list.head._2  // 1.0

s_list.tail.foldLeft( (s_list.head._1, s_list.head._2, ndLimit, List.empty[Long]) ){
  (acc, x) =>
    if (x._2 <= acc._3)
      (x._1, x._2, acc._2, acc._1 :: acc._4)
    else
      (x._1, x._2, acc._3, acc._4)
}._4.reverse
// res1: List[Long] = List(103, 106, 107)
```

Note that a tuple of `( previous ts, previous nd, current ndLimit, list of timestamps )` is used as the accumulator to carry over items from the previous row for the necessary comparison logic in the current row.

Comment: this is not the end of dataset , its just data which satisfied the condition ,and after that data is still there. but i need the last value only. and want to pick the last ts value here. and for another loop i want to start the loop based on that value

Comment: @stackoverflow, please see revised answer.

Comment: thanx mate but this solved case. here is what exactly i m struck https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52758059/looping-on-spark-sql-scala-dataframe?noredirect=1#comment92439314_52758059