# What is the equivalent of pandas.DataFrame.tail in DataBricks

Tags: python, pandas, databricks

What is the equivalent of pandas.DataFrame.tail in DataBricks ? I search a bit in the documentation but didn't found any relevant function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DataBricks is apparently using `pyspark.sql` dataframes, not `pandas`.

```
# Index the df if you haven't already
# Note that monotonically increasing id has size limits
from pyspark.sql.functions import monotonically_increasing_id
df = df.withColumn("index", monotonically_increasing_id())

# Query with the index
tail = sqlContext.sql("""SELECT * FROM df ORDER BY index DESC limit 5""")
tail.show()
```

Note that this is expensive and doesn't play to the strengths of `Spark`.

See also:

https://medium.com/@chris_bour/6-differences-between-pandas-and-spark-dataframes-1380cec394d2

[pyspark,spark: how to select last row and also how to access pyspark dataframe by index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39544796/pyspark-spark-how-to-select-last-row-and-also-how-to-access-pyspark-dataframe-b)