# How to get last row data from Pyspark dataframe and then delete it

Tags: python, apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark

I read in a csv file that has a tail looks like below. It's a wide table with about 50 columns so I didn't list them all. Line starts with H is the header, and the last line starts with T is the footer. I am trying to get the number from last line, `2` in this example, which is the row count. After checking the row count I want to delete the last line (headerline was removed when read the dataframe).

Is there a way of getting the number and removing the last line without converting the dataframe back to an RDD? I saw this question here but wonder if it can be done without the `monotonically_increasing_id`[How to select last row and also how to access PySpark dataframe by index?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39544796/how-to-select-last-row-and-also-how-to-access-pyspark-dataframe-by-index) Many thanks for your help.

Edited: Zipwithindex is for rdd not dataframe right? I hope not having to convert it to RDD and then back again

```
H~headerString~201908~stringE
D~stringA~stringB~stringC
D~stringAA~stringBB~stringCC
T~2~stringD~footerString
```

Comment: Everything that can be done is described in that answer. Like zero323 says, you can use zipWithIndex...

Comment: This still doesn't change the answer.

Comment: To get the row-count `2`, use `df.where('c1 == "T"').first().c2` where c1, c2 are the column names of the 1st and 2nd field in your sample data. to filter out footer, just `df.where('c1 != "T"')`