# Pyspark dataframe add list as column

Tags: python, pyspark

I have a python  list (`p_list`) with 0 and 1 with as many elements as a spark dataframe that has one column only (all elements, are like: `'imaj7felb438l6hk'`, ....).

And I am trying to add this list as column into the spark dataframe (`df_cookie`). But there is no key. So far I tried:

1) Transform `df_cookie` into rdd, doesn't work, as it is really big and I run out of memory

2) Transform `df_cookie` into a pandas df, doesn't work (same reasons as 1))

3) Transform the list into a new dataframe, and use `monotonically_increasing_id()`, to get a common key and link both. This doesn't work either, as i end up with different ids in each dataframe.

Any suggestions?

```
test_list = [i for i in range(cookie.count())]
res = spark.createDataFrame(test_list, IntegerType()).toDF('ind')
df_res = res.withColumn('row', monotonically_increasing_id())
df_res.show(5)
+---+---+
|ind|row|
+---+---+
|  0|  0|
|  1|  1|
|  2|  2|
|  3|  3|
|  4|  4|
+---+---+

df_cookie = cookie.withColumn('row', monotonically_increasing_id())
df_cookie.show(5)
+--------------------+-----------+
|              cookie|        row|
+--------------------+-----------+
|    imaj7felb438l6hk|68719476736|
|hk3l641k5r1m2umv2...|68719476737|
|    ims1arqgxczr6rfm|68719476738|
|2t4rlplypc1ks1hnf...|68719476739|
|17gpx1x3j5eq03dpw...|68719476740|
+--------------------+-----------+
```

Desired output:

```
+--------------------+-----------+
|              cookie|        ind|
+--------------------+-----------+
|    imaj7felb438l6hk|          0|
|hk3l641k5r1m2umv2...|          1|
|    ims1arqgxczr6rfm|          2|
|2t4rlplypc1ks1hnf...|          3|
|17gpx1x3j5eq03dpw...|          4|
+--------------------+-----------+
```

Comment: Please provide a sample of your data, as well as the code you have tried so far & the results, otherwise it is impossible to help; see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I just edited my questions, including pieces of the code.

Comment: Good, but still the *desired* outcome is missing - provide an example of what exactly your desired result is

Comment: Hope it's enough now.

Comment: Not sure it is possible - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32760888/pyspark-dataframes-way-to-enumerate-without-converting-to-pandas?noredirect=1&lq=1 ; and from the [`monotonically_increasing_id` docs](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.monotonically_increasing_id), "The generated ID is guaranteed to be monotonically increasing and unique, but not consecutive."

Comment: That doesn't really help. I also tried to do this:
    from pyspark.sql.window import Window
    w = Window.orderBy()
    indexed = cookie.withColumn("index", row_number().over(w))

But I get the following error:
 u'Window function row_number() requires window to be ordered, please add ORDER BY clause. For example SELECT row_number()(value_expr) OVER (PARTITION BY window_partition ORDER BY window_ordering) from table;'