# How to create row_index for a Spark dataframe using window.partionBy()?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a Dataframe with single column like shown below.

```
Type
'BAT'
'BAT'
'BALL'
'BAT'
'BALL'
'BALL'
```

To the above dataframe I have added a new column called 'const'.

```
df = df.withColumn('const',F.lit(1))
```

How do I perform a cumsum using window.partionBy() on 'const' column and create new row_id column?

**Expected Output**

```
Type  row_id
'BAT'   1
'BAT'   2
'BALL'  3
'BAT'   4
'BALL'  5
'BALL'  6
```

I also dont want to use RDD, everything should be in Dataframe due to performance reasons.

**EDIT**

- I want the row id to increment by +1
- Dont want to use monotonically_increasing() function due to above reason

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PySpark DataFrames - way to enumerate without converting to Pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32760888/pyspark-dataframes-way-to-enumerate-without-converting-to-pandas)

Comment: No just went to the link you shared. Not at all a duplicate and the link doesn't answer the question here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you just want a row index without taking into account the values, then use :

```
df = df.withColumn('row_id',F.monotonically_increasing_id())
```

this will create a unic index for each line.

If you want to take into account your values, and have the same index for a duplicate value, then use rank:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
w = Window().partitionBy().orderBy("type")
df = df.withColumn('row_id',F.rank().over(w))
```

You can of course achieve the same with sum or row_number, but the 2 methods above are better i think.

```
import sys
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
w = Window().partitionBy().orderBy().rowsBetween(-sys.maxsize,0)
df = df.withColumn('row_id',F.sum("const").over(w))
```

or

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
w = Window().partitionBy().orderBy("const")
df = df.withColumn('row_id',F.row_number().over(w))
```

Comment: Thanks F.row_number() is working for me. But F.sum("const") is not working, how do i fix it?

Comment: F.sum("const")  code is giving value 10 in all the rows

Comment: One qq what if my data has more than sys.maxsize rows?

Comment: How to use UNBOUNDED PRECEDING as mentioned in the below blog https://databricks.com/blog/2015/07/15/introducing-window-functions-in-spark-sql.html

Comment: Window.unboundedPreceding appear in 2.1. otherwise you have to use the sys.maxsize. The frame is unbounded if this is `Window.unboundedPreceding`, or any value less than or equal to max(-`sys.maxsize`, -9223372036854775808)

Comment: you have more than 1E19 lines ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163241/discussion-between-ml-pro-and-steven-benet).