# Stack Spark dataframes horizontally - equivalent to pandas concat or r cbind

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe

Is there a way to append a `dataframe` horizontally to another one - assuming both have identical number of rows?

This would be the equivalent of `pandas` `concat` by `axis=1`;

```
result = pd.concat([df1, df4], axis=1)
```

or the `R` `cbind`

Answer (score 8):

There wouldn't be one. Unlike Pandas `DataFrame`, Spark `DataFrame` is more a relation, and has no inherent order.

There is known pattern, where you convert data to `RDD`, `zipWithIndex` ([PySpark DataFrames - way to enumerate without converting to Pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32760888/9627366))  and then `join` using index field, but it is ultimately an antipattern*.

---

* If we don't explicitly guarantee specific order (and who know what happens under the hood with all new bells and whistles like cost based optimizer and custom optimizer rules) then it can easily become brittle and silently fail in some unexpected way.

Comment: Your comments (/answer) here ring true. I'll wait to see what other ideas come in.  The `zipwithIndex` will actually likely be the approach in the end. ooc why do you call it an `antipattern`?

Comment: If we don't explicitly guarantee specific order (and who know what happens under the hood with all new bells and whistles like cost based optimizer and custom optimizer rules) then it can easily become brittle and silently fail in some unexpected way.

Comment: hmm, i'll think about that wrt `zipWithIndex`:  in any case it is always possible to provide an explicit ordering preceding that operation.

Comment: hey user9627366 where did you go to? why did you disappear?  (i had upvoted you and you were in pole position for getting accepted answer..)

Comment: When revisiting this years later I can't agree there is no explicit ordering . That is after all provided by `order by` in a SQL .