# Horizontal concatenation in Pyspark

Tags: pyspark

is there an equivalent on pyspark that allow me to do similar operation as in Pandas

```
pd.contact(df1, df2, Axis=1)
```

I have tried several methods so far none of them seems to work. the concatenation that it does is vertical, and I'm needing to concatenate multiple spark dataframes into 1 whole dataframe.

if I use union or unionAll it the dataframes get stacked vertically, as one single column which is not useful for my use case. I also have tried this example (did not work either):

```
from functools import reduce  
from pyspark.sql import DataFrame

def unionAll(*dfs):
     return reduce(DataFrame.unionAll, dfs)
```

any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49763009/stack-spark-dataframes-horizontally-equivalent-to-pandas-concat-or-r-cbind

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Stack Spark dataframes horizontally - equivalent to pandas concat or r cbind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49763009/stack-spark-dataframes-horizontally-equivalent-to-pandas-concat-or-r-cbind)

Comment: Thank you, I see now there isn't a simplified way to do it. as Pandas will handle that piece.  besides converting between pandas and pyspark just crashes everything. again thank you both. the post was really helpful on this matter.

Comment: I did find a way to join multiple spark dataframes though. using crossJoin function.

Answer (score 1):

The best way I have found is to join the dataframes using a unique id, and org.apache.spark.sql.functions.**monotonically_increasing_id()** happens to do the job

The following code in scala (would be the same in pyspark):

```scala
Set(df1, df2, df3).map(_.withColumn("id", monotonically_increasing_id()))
                  .reduce((a,b) => a.join(b, "id"))
```

Gives the horizontally concatenated dataframes.

Comment: Thank you for doing this  :)! I did take a different approach, but it will be good to have your response as a reference if I come across this type of problem again.