# How can I combine multiple dataframes horizontally, based on 1 column, in Pyspark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, concatenation

I want to combine these 3 dataframes, based on their `ID` columns, and get the below output. I am after a short way that I can use it for combining many more number of dataframes later.

Input:

```
+---+---+---+
| ID|  a|  b|
+---+---+---+
|  A|  1|  1|
|  B|  2|  2|
+---+---+---+
+---+---+---+
| ID|  c|  d|
+---+---+---+
|  A|  3|333|
|  B|  4|444|
+---+---+---+
+---+---+---+
| ID|  e|  f|
+---+---+---+
|  A|555|  5|
|  B|666|  6|
+---+---+---+
```

Output:

```
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| ID|  a|  b|  c|  d|  e|  f|
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|  A|  1|  1|  3|333|555|  5|
|  B|  2|  2|  4|444|666|  6|
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

Answer:
For anyone who might find it useful later!

```
# create list of dataframes
list_df = [df1, df2, df3]

# merge all at once
df_all = reduce(lambda x, y: x.join(y, on="ID"), list_df)
```

Comment: This question may have already been answered here (unfortunately it looks like it's not possible, or difficult): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49763009/stack-spark-dataframes-horizontally-equivalent-to-pandas-concat-or-r-cbind

Comment: Did I miss something? Is that just df1 inner join df2 inner join df3 based on id column?

Comment: @JonathanLam it is what you said, but I am after a shorter way that I don't have to bring all one after another. So, that I can use it later for more number of dataframes.

Answer (score 0):

The 3 dataframes can be jioned according to the ID column.

```
df = df1.join(df2, 'ID').join(df3, 'ID')
```